# Android: Does an AlertDialog.show() start a new thread?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Does an `AlertDialog.show()` start a new thread?  I don't see any indication in the Android documentation that it does, and would like confirmation.

Specifically, I want to make sure that the `OnDismiss()` callback occurs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: No, it doesn't create a new thread and yes it runs in the ui thread.

Long: It **should** be running in the ui thread since it modifies ui stuff but you can create it from another thread and you will end having an exception. If you have a second thread you should do all the `AlertDialog` calls from the ui thread using one of the different ways to communicating with the ui thread. For instance [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

No.  The AlertDialog is kicked off on the current Activity thread.  Anything you want to do in the background would need to be done on a seperate thread ( Thread, AsyncTask, etc.).   When dismissing the dialog, you indeed need to call the dismiss from the Activity thread.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it does not. There is no reason why it would. But to be sure you can inspect the source code.